# Passing data to drawer fragments Android Java

Tags: java, android

I am struggling with passing data from PopUpActivity to fragment used in Drewer Navigation Menu.

So far I tried some solutions but only one went without compilation errors but still isn't working.

I have fragment where I created function to create new instance:

```
class LocationsFragment extends Fragment {

...

public static LocationsFragment newInstance(String name) {
    LocationsFragment locationsFragment = new LocationsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", name);
    locationsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return locationsFragment;
}
}
```

and then in my popup activity, I try to call it while I click on one of buttons:

```
gotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LocationsFragment.newInstance(name);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

But I realised that this function wasn't called after clicking on btn
How to pass data in that scenario properly?

Comment: what the behavior you expect when the button is clicked?

Comment: in this fragment i have map fragment and list view

listview have onClick listener which open popup
from that pop up i wanted to use goto btn to go back to fragment and set map zoom to location provided from popup>>listViewItem
but after short break i thought that i dont need button in popup to do it but instead i put equivalent method in listView onClick method which do the same without troublemaking data passing betwen Activity and Fragment
Problem solved, Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: Calling `newInstance(name)` just creates a fragment .. same like creating any object..  to make it effective, it needs to be added/replaced using a transaction

Comment: please show code that getting arguments, It maybe helpful for resolving

Comment: yeah i used transactions before and that was problematic instead of this i changed some logic and the result is almost the same